# Find all values for a, b, c, and d, such that the following matrix equation is consistent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I need to find the values for the given variables to make the below equation consistent. I've tried setting the corresponding entries equal to each other and solving the system for a, b, c, d, but I'm not sure how to do that if there are many other x variables. How do I go about answering this question?

\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}-3x_{2}+2x_{4}&-2x_{4}+5x_{5}+b\\3x_{1}-x_{3}+7x_{5}&9x_{2}+6x_{4}-d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2x_{5}+a&-2x_{1}+6x_{2}+x_{3}\\9x_{2}+c&3x_{1}-2x_{3}+8x_{5}\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0):

Here what to do for $a$

You have $x_{1}-3x_{2}+2x_{4}=-2x_{5}+a$

so $a=x_{1}-3x_{2}+2x_{4}+2x_{5}$.

You can try $b,c,d$

Comment: I was able to isolate a, b, c, d in their equations. Is the only way to solve in terms of x?

Comment: @Sloopy Not really. You have four linear equations so you can solve exactly for $a,b,c,d$ in terms of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$, but not for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$  in terms of $a,b,c,d$ as you would have too many unknowns